# How do you add a variable.value as the parameter of range()?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge the first three empty rows and write Activity# in the three merged cells. I can't even figure out how to select 3 custom cells to get them ready for merging. I checked everywhere online but range(A1:B2) is always given a definitive range. How do I write for example: range(variable_A1:variable_B2)?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

Dim beginning
Dim ending
Dim selection

beginning = Cells(empty_row.Value, 2)
ending = Cells(empty_row.Value + 2, 2)


'this is supposed to select 3 cells, but it doesn't work
selection = Range("beginning:ending").Select
'figure out how to merge cells below


Cells(empty_row.Value, 2).Value = "Activity" & Activity_number.Value


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To nb_subs.Value
    Cells(empty_row.Value + i + 2, 2).Value = "Sub-Activity" & i
Next i
```

Comment: `Set selection = Range(beginning,ending)` also use `Set` to begining and ending.  You set ranges.  Also declare them as Ranges `Dim beginning as Range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim beginning As Range
Dim ending As Range
Dim selection As Range

With Sheet1

    Set beginning = .Cells(empty_row.Value, 2)
    Set ending = .Cells(empty_row.Value + 2, 2)


    'this is supposed to select 3 cells, but it doesn't work
    Set selection = .Range(beginning, ending)
    selection.Merge


    selection.Value = "Activity" & Activity_number.Value


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To nb_subs.Value
        .Cells(empty_row.Value + i + 2, 2).Value = "Sub-Activity" & i
    Next i
End With
```